# Are the Goldtip and Easton spine declarations AMO/AMA or ASTM?

Tags: archery, arrows

I need to convert the spine of my Goldtip and Easton shafts to the AMO static spine standardization. They've their static spine declared as for example "500" which translates into a deflection of "0.500". But with which measurement method? The AMO/AMA with 2 # @ 26 " or ASTM with 1.94 # @ 28 "?

Comment: I truly believe Easton, Carbon Express and Gold Tip use the static measurement method. (a 1.94# weight hung dead centre in the middle of a 28'' shaft)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I once called GoldTip and got an amazing person on the line who not only answered my question, but spent time talking about the "why" of the question.  I would suggestion trying to call GoldTip and ask.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/what-is-the-difference-between-amo-ama-and-astm-spine-declarations