# What is the difference between AMO/AMA and ASTM spine declarations?

Tags: archery, terminology

This [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15406/are-the-goldtip-and-easton-spine-declarations-amo-ama-or-astm) asks "Are the Goldtip and Easton spine declarations AMO/AMA or ASTM??",

What exactly is the difference between AMO/AMA and ASTM  spine declarations and what difference does it make?